# Directx mesh vertices problem

Tags: c++, directx

I use DirectX to create a boxmesh,and I want to get the vertices position in the mesh,

but I find the 24 vertices are wrong!

or is there any way to use the 24 vertices???
here is my code

```
D3DXCreateBox(pd3dDevice,2,2,2,&g_model,NULL);

DWORD size=g_model->GetNumVertices();g_model->GetVertexBuffer(&Points);

Points->Lock(0,0,(void**)&v,0);   


for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 vertcle(v[i].x,v[i].y,v[i].z);
    Pos.push_back(vertcle);
};

Points->Unlock();
```

The vectorPos is this:

`Pos[24]({-1, -1, -1},{-1, 0, 0},{-1, -1, 1},{-1, 0, 0},{-1, 1, 1},{-1, 0, 0},{-1, 1, -1},{-1, 0, 0},{-1, 1, -1},{0, 1, 0},{-1, 1, 1},{0, 1, 0},{1, 1, 1},{0, 1, 0},{1, 1, -1},{0, 1, 0},{1, 1, -1},{1, 0, 0},{1, 1, 1},{1, 0, 0},{1, -1, 1},{1, 0, 0},{1, -1, -1},{1, 0, 0})   std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3,std::allocator<D3DXVECTOR3> >`
you can notice some position are wrong(-1,0,0)....

Comment: What format did you use to define your vértices? I'm trying to do something very similar but I don't know how D3DXCreateBox defines the format for vértices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vertex buffer contains normals as well as positions -- The odd vectors are the normals.

Try:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 vertcle(v[2*i].x,v[2*i].y,v[2*i].z);
    Pos.push_back(vertcle);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!GOD DAMN IT!NO BOOK TELL MEdo such thing!